# Unclosed quotation mark after the character string 'NOT LIKE'C"."

Tags: sql, syntax

This clause works in another query

```
WHERE "PD"."STATUS" NOT LIKE 'C'
    AND "PD"."QUANTITY"<>"PD"."QUANTITY_REC"
    AND "PO"."DeletedFlag"=0
    AND
    (
        "PO"."COBR"='5634'
        OR "PO"."COBR"='1234'
        OR "PO"."COBR"='5678'
        OR "PO"."COBR"='4321'
        OR "PO"."COBR"='8765'
    )
    AND "IM"."PUR_ON_ORDER">0
    AND "MT"."NUMBER"='15'
    AND "PO"."STATUS" NOT LIKE 'C'
```

but in a new query I keep getting the error

> Unclosed quotation mark after the character string 'NOT LIKE'C"."

Comment: If you want help with syntax, then you better tell us what language you're using. Please read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: Rookie mistake...SQL

Comment: Have you copy-pasted the *full* and *complete* SQL statement? It doesn't look like it. And is the error message also copy-pasted in full and complete?

Comment: I have not.  I'm new to this site and not sure of how to format the code.

Comment: We can help you with the formatting (and you can always read [the editing help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for help about question formatting yourself). What's more important is that your question include all information, which includes complete statements.